# Where is the original CryptoNote Java implementation?

Tags: cryptonote, source, implementation, source-code-documentation

Supposedly CryptoNote was first implemented in Java and soon after migrated to C++.

Where can I get the original Java implementation?

I don't see it on GitHub and I can't get access to the official CryptoNote forum, so I can't ask there.

Comment: I didn't find anything and thus opened an [issue on GitHub](https://github.com/cryptonotefoundation/cryptonote/issues/303). Let's see if we can get an answer

Comment: Someone asked on [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/Monero/comments/kye0un/the_original_cryptonote_java_implementation_where/) as well, but to date no answers there either

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe it ever existed/exists anymore. The only source for the original Java implementation I found is from the [CryptoNote - BitcoinWiki](https://en.bitcoinwiki.org/wiki/Cryptonote) page. The [citation](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/889000/Programming-Languages-Comparison-Cryptocurrency-Pe) leads to a page deleted in 2015, but the [archive](https://archive.ph/y1mdq) references the following quote:

> CryptoNote used to be written in Java but then migrated to C++ in 2013.

However, according to the famous [Blowing the lid off the CryotoNote/Bytecoin scam](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=740112.0), ByteCoin was not released earlier than March, 2014, meaning for there to be a public Java implementation, it would have to be floating around before the release date. To me, this reads like another red herring ByteCoin used to cover their premine.

In case I'm wrong, I've sent out a [Tweet](https://twitter.com/pancakesareyum8/status/1532034248143687683) to Andrey Sabelnikov, one of the original authors of CryptoNote who worked with Nicolas Van Saberhagen. There may be more to the story there.